# html font size max value

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

What is the max value of the font-size in pixel which browsers accept? Is it possible to get this value (depending on browser) using javascript?

Example:

> 1) formattedText.css('fontSize', 200);
>            Result: formattedText.height() = 201
>
> 2) formattedText.css('fontSize', 2000);
>            Result: formattedText.height() = 2001
>
> 3) formattedText.css('fontSize', 20000);
>            **Result: formattedText.height() = 2001**

Comment: My guess is there may be some "logical" maximum size that you shouldn't go over (like 65535 for a maximum line-height) if you want to be compatible with as many situations as possible. But there's no such hard limit in the formal specs, if that's what you mean!

Comment: formattedText = $('<span>A</span>'); //jquery